# Need to design a query to extract data

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES 
(   
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMERIC(6,0), 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20), 
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_LAST_NAME_NN" NOT NULL, 
    EMAIL VARCHAR(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_NN" NOT NULL, 
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(20), 
    HIRE_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT "EMP_HIRE_DATE_NN" NOT NULL, 
    JOB_ID VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT "EMP_JOB_NN" NOT NULL, 
    SALARY NUMERIC(8,2), 
    COMMISSION_PCT NUMERIC(2,2), 
    MANAGER_ID NUMERIC(6,0), 
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMERIC(4,0), 
);
```

I am new to SQL and my assignment requires me to List the employee details if and only if more than 10 employees are present in department number 50. Following is what I did so far,

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = '50'
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
HAVING COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) > 10
```

But I get an error

> Column 'EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I think you need to go over this ----> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: You can't have the `*` as is in the `select` list. Try changing it specify the exact columns that you want.

Comment: Quick fix would be to put each field you're selecting in your group by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, HIRE_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IN (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = 50
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
HAVING COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID)> 10)
```